# Create a general func from particular function (refactoring)

Tags: postgresql, go, refactoring, bulkinsert, pq

I'm using the `createUsers` func to populate my fake DB, just for tests.

I'm using the bulk imports feature of `pq` (https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#hdr-Bulk_imports).

```golang
func createUsers() {

    users := []models.User{}

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        users = append(users, models.User{Username: "username"+i, Age: i})
    }

    connStr := "user=postgres password=postgres dbname=dbname sslmode=disable"
    DB, err = sql.Open("postgres", connStr)
    checkErr(err)

    txn, err := DB.Begin()
    checkErr(err)

    stmt, err := txn.Prepare(pq.CopyIn("users", "username", "age"))
    checkErr(err)

    for _, user := range users {
        _, err = stmt.Exec(user.Username, user.Age)
        checkErr(err)
    }

    _, err = stmt.Exec()
    checkErr(err)

    err = stmt.Close()
    checkErr(err)

    err = txn.Commit()
    checkErr(err)
}
```

Everything in this code is working good.

**THE NEED:**

What I need now is to make it "general", not just for User model.

I think I need something like:

```golang
DBBulkInsert(users, "users", "username", "age")
```

with func `DBBulkInsert` like:

```golang
func DBBulkInsert(rows []interface{}, tableName string, tableColumns ...string) {
    // DB var from connection func

    txn, err := DB.Begin()
    checkErr(err)

    stmt, err := txn.Prepare(pq.CopyIn(tableName, tableColumns...))
    checkErr(err)

    for _, row := range rows {
        _, err = stmt.Exec(row[0], row[1]) //THIS IS TOTALLY WRONG! WHAT TO DO HERE?
        checkErr(err)
    }

    _, err = stmt.Exec()
    checkErr(err)

    err = stmt.Close()
    checkErr(err)

    err = txn.Commit()
    checkErr(err)
}
```

**THE PROBLEM:**

Obviously `_, err = stmt.Exec(row[0], row[1])` is totally wrong. I don't understand how to call `DBBulkInsert` with my users array.

**STILL BETTER:**

Maybe I can remove also the parameters `"users", "username", "age"` in `DBBulkInsert(users, "users", "username", "age")`, but how? Reflection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `rows` type needs to be `[][]interface{}`, i.e. a list of rows where each row is a list of column values. Then with that type each single `row` can be "unpacked" into the `Exec` call using `...`.

That is:

```
for _, row := range rows {
    _, err = stmt.Exec(row...)
}
```

To get from `[]model.User` or `[]model.Whatever` to `[][]interface{}` you'll need to use reflection. And if you want, you can also use reflection to get the column names and the table name as well.

Say you have a model type like:

```
type User struct {
    _        struct{} `rel:"users"`
    Username string   `col:"username"`
    Age      int      `col:"age"`
}
```

now you could use reflection to get table name and the list of columns from the fields' struct tags. (Note that use of the `_` (blank) field is just one option of how to specify the table name, it has its downsides and upsides so it's up to you to choose, here I'm just trying to demonstrate how the reflect package can be leveraged).

The following is a more complete example of how to collect the "meta" data from tags and how to aggregate the column values from struct fields.

```
func DBBulkInsert(source interface{}) {
    slice := reflect.ValueOf(source)
    if slice.Kind() != reflect.Slice {
        panic("not a slice")
    }

    elem := slice.Type().Elem()
    if elem.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        elem = elem.Elem()
    }
    if elem.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        panic("slice elem not a struct, nor a pointer to a struct")
    }

    // get table and column names
    var tableName string
    var cols []string
    for i := 0; i < elem.NumField(); i++ {
        f := elem.Field(i)
        if rel := f.Tag.Get("rel"); len(rel) > 0 {
            tableName = rel
        }
        if col := f.Tag.Get("col"); len(col) > 0 {
            cols = append(cols, col)
        }
    }

    // aggregate rows
    rows := [][]interface{}{}
    for i := 0; i < slice.Len(); i++ {
        m := slice.Index(i)
        if m.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
            m = m.Elem()
        }

        vals := []interface{}{}
        for j := 0; j < m.NumField(); j++ {
            ft := m.Type().Field(j)
            if col := ft.Tag.Get("col"); len(col) > 0 {
                f := m.Field(j)
                vals = append(vals, f.Interface())
            }
        }

        rows = append(rows, vals)
    }

    // ...
}
```

[Run it on playground](https://play.golang.com/p/Gi-P2_AYhBv)

Comment: Your code is amazing. What if I can't use tags on models's structs?

Comment: And the other problem is the table name can be different (ex: "TeamId" can be "team_id" on DB) and without tags I think it's impossible and I need to pass also this information to the func. Am I wrong?

Comment: @FredHors in that case another option would be to create a map of `reflect.Type`s to table names and columns, but you would need to make sure that the columns are in the same order as the fields. So anytime the order of the fields changes or a field is added/removed you need to also adjust the slice of columns. https://play.golang.com/p/cohQ3rg3BvV

Comment: Amazing. I tried: it works. I'm learning a lot thanks to you: THANKS! Just the last doubt is if I create an array without all fields: let's say just `DBBulkInsert([]User{{Username: "Joe"}, {Username: "Jack"}})` without `Age` field or without `Username`. What do you think about?

Comment: @FredHors In Go doing `User{Username:"Joe"}` is the same as `User{Username:"Joe", Age: 0}` and `User{Age: 21}` is the same as `User{Username:"", Age: 21}`. Fields not listed in the *composite literal* will be automatically initialized to their *zero value*.

Comment: The problem here is with `gorm.Model` in my model struct which holds 4 columns: `"id", "created_at", "updated_at", "deleted_at"` and the problem is: `2019/03/17 22:12:41 [] sql: converting argument $1 type: unsupported type gorm.Model, a struct`. Maybe I can skip it in `vals` loop? What do you think about?

Comment: Or maybe I can avoid the use of `gorm.Model` and simply declare all the fields by myself. Even because I'm using Gorm just now for the MVP.

Comment: @FredHors skipping a field is certainly an option and in the case of `gorm.Model` probably the right one.